# why does apple devices play html5 videos in its own player?

Tags: ios, overlay, html5-video, ads

I tried different html players and used html5 video tag. However apple devices (ipod touch 4, iphone 4, ipad) shows html5 videos in its **own player**.

My main goal is to show overlay adverts on video. I decided to hide/show div with the help of absolute positioning and z-index. It worked for browsers in my PC, however couldn't manage in apple devices.

In order to show advert on apple devices, firstly I need to use my own html5 player, not apple's default video player.

Is my approach possible or are there any workarounds? Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

**editted**

There is an attribute "webkit-playsinline". But that does not work either. I think it only works in app programming with UIWebView.

```
<video id="video" width="480" height="320" webkit-playsinline>
```

Comment: In your source you try to use webkit player. Yes, safari is a webkit. But apple override it. Like some css-style can override standard classes.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but you can't use another player. Any browser with html5 supporting can you few different players. Every player build in to browser. It is part of browser.
When you use your apple device for browsing you can use only Safari (and Opera). Safari has only 1 player for html5-video. And Opera use safari-implementation of player :)